# Graph database modeling graph tools?

Tags: neo4j

A good graph image is good for the graph database documentation like UML diagram, like the

[image]

Is there any tool support do draw this diagram in the market totally free?

Comment: That diagram is drawn with http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/ for which you can find the code at https://github.com/apcj/arrows.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Thanks Tom, I just copy his comment as the answer here so it will more helpful and better for searching.

> That diagram is drawn with [apcjones.com/arrows](http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/) for which you can find the code at [github.com/apcj/arrows](https://github.com/apcj/arrows)

Comment: From description: "Are there any limitations? Yes, lots. Consider the current version experimental at best. There hasn't been any work on browser compatibility, so I'd be surprised if it works properly outside WebKit." So, it is probably not suitable for production.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with JavaScript, than you have a lot of options and D3 is only the one of them.

But I see, Liping Huang, that your top tag is **Java**. So you can look at [gephi-toolkit](https://gephi.org/toolkit/)

It is rather cumbersome, but is native java without any web technologies.

Pros:

1. it can generate graphs with thousands or even hundreds of thousands of nodes.
2. It has a lot more settings and engines

Cons:

1. For some operations it requires JVM to be started NOT in headless mode, but this can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at D3.Js(https://d3js.org/). 
It is a good open source JavaScript framework for data visualization.

Comment: Thanks. I know D3 JS, basically "apcjones.com/arrows" is build based on D3 too, what I need a the diagram tool which can modeling the graph database.